# Изменить иконку формы CSharpCodeProvider c#

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

Динамически компилирую ехе

```
 CodeDomProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(compilerInfo);
                CompilerParameters Params = new CompilerParameters();

            Params.OutputAssembly = fileName;
                Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
                Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
                Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");          
                Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Net.dll");

             Params.CompilerOptions += "/t:winexe";
            Params.CompilerOptions +=" /win32icon:icon.ico";

            Params.GenerateExecutable = true;
```

Иконка для ехе ставится таким образом `Params.CompilerOptions +=" /win32icon:icon.ico";`, но при запуске ехе (вин приложение с формой), то на форме стандартная иконка, можно и ее поменять ?

Comment: Иконка на форме - это свойство самого экземпляра формы, как вы её устанавливаете?

Comment: Когда вы меняете иконку формы в дизайнере, студия добавляет строчку `this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));` в метод `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: @Андрей ясно,спасибо, я просто вырубил иконку